# Opening maps and chose car/on foot/cycle path

Tags: ios, apple-maps

I am stuck... is there any way to the screen where you can pick if you will travel by car / cycle / on foot? I am getting this image

[image]

But I want this one.

[image]

this is my method

```
   /*
    *   Open navigation and start to navigate
    */
    @IBAction func navigationStart(sender: AnyObject) {

        let lat1 : NSString = self.targetLatitudeString
        let lng1 : NSString = self.targetLongtitudeString

        let latitute:CLLocationDegrees =  lat1.doubleValue
        let longitute:CLLocationDegrees =  lng1.doubleValue

        let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitute, longitute)
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
        let options = [
            MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
            MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
        ]
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = nameString
        MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([mapItem], launchOptions: options)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
```

this will do the magic